# Set a value to a row in a certain column of a listview by knowing the tag and without looping through items

Tags: c#

Is there any chance to set a value to a row in a certain column without looping through the items of the listview if I know the TAG of the row?

For example

```
|Column1|Column2|Column3
   1       A        A
   2       B        B
   3       C        C
```

For example if I want to set the value "OK" to the column3 in the first row :

```
listView1.Items.Column[2].Text == "OK" Where listview1.Items.Tag == "MyTag"
```

Is there anything similar like the example given?(ofc what I've written is just an example and something like that doesn't exist);

The only way of doing this as I know is to loop through the items ,find the tag and set the value to the column but I would like to know if there's any other way of doing this/

Comment: Presentation and business logic should be entirely separate concerns.  Change the value in the underlying data source to your listview, and then rebind the listview so it shows the updates.  What is your listview bound to currently?  A database of some sort?

Comment: my listview is created dynamically and items are added in the same way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the LINQ to get the same result , you can also do the same filter if you are getting from the database. I want to make clear , what ever short form you use they all have to iterate through the data to match it . There is no escape from the looping , may be LINQ make you feel that it is one line but internally they also loop. I had also worked the same way earlier but no skipping of looping , even some time using your own loop you can have some business logic to find the value faster.

Comment: Indeed but its kinda weird..I mean what If I have 1000 rows in the listview..I need to loop each time through them and update the one I need..damn

Comment: See that is where you can either use sorting so that you can reach some time faster and break the loop. I think this is the reason why all the Database uses Indexes to make search faster :) . Think if you can apply something

Comment: Thanks for the idea of using indexes.That would help.